# Image compression for website

Tags: image, performance, web, compression, pagespeed

I develop a website that uses a lot of images and it's starting to get really slow. In some pages I have to show hundreds of images, so it gets messy.

I have a structure of folders with different ID's, each one with 4-5 images. And each image is around 300Kb!! I realize that it's not enough compression for the web.

I need some tips to compress all this pictures. The problem with the structure folders is that I need to open each folder and change the pictures inside and I can't just compress them all at the same time with some compression software.

Also, is there a way to compress the pictures on the server side before it goes to the client side?

I'm definitely not an expert in image compression so I need a lot of help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Mac OS or Linux you can use command line:

```
//single image
convert -quality 70 image.jpg image.jpg

//folder
for f in *.jpg; do convert -quality 70 $f $f; done
```

For Windows you have to download external mass edit program

Also if you have a alot of images on a single page you could use 'lazy loading' technique. Loading a part of your page on demand. So you will load couple of images on page load and if the user scrolls down ajax will fire with request for another junk of images.

Answer (score -1):

Give the image some bash love.

```
find image/path -type f -name '*.PNG' -exec sips -s formatOptions  40 {} \;
```

This will go throw every subfolder you have and make all of them smaller instantly.

Comment: Please do not leave promotional links like that; read [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).